# Connect Rstudio to oracle database with WE8MSWIN1252 encoding

Tags: r, oracle, dplyr, rodbc

I have issues with wrong encoding when connecting to an Oracle database from RStudio. I have tried both the `RODBC` and `ODBC` packages.

When I query the database either with `sqlQuery()` or through `dplyr` Norwegian letters (Æ, Ø and Å) is not displayed correctly.

I have tried setting the default text encoding i RStudio to UTF-8, and saving the R-scripts with UTF-8 encoding, but the problem persists.

When querying the database with `SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS` I find that the database has `NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252`, so I have tried to specify this when connecting.

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "RStudio", uid = "user", 
                 pwd = "password", encoding = "WE8MSWIN1252")
```

But this only gives me this error message:

```
Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
Can't convert from WE8MSWIN1252 to UTF-8
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The name WE8MSWIN1252 is an Oracle invention.  It might be the same as (or similar to) "WINDOWS-1252" or "CP1252" (which I think are the same).

Comment: Yes, you're right. It should probably be "windows-1252" instead. That still doesn't help though, instead I get this error: `Error in iconv(query, to = enc) : 
  unsupported conversion from '' to 'windows 1252' in codepage 1252`

Comment: That's strange:  your original had an error converting *from* an encoding, this has an error converting *to* an encoding.  Also, the error spells the encoding differently than you did.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding argument in dbConnect should be set to the encoding used by the system in which you run R, rather than the encoding used in the database (in accordance with the NLS_LANG system environment variable). Therefore, if you run R/Rstudio on a Windows machine, 'encoding = "cp1252"' or 'encoding="latin1"' should do it. However, if you're on Linux or Mac, 'encoding="UTF8" should hopefully work'. If this does not work, make sure that NLS_LANG is set correctly.

(If you use Rstudio server, you have to set NLS_LANG in your .Renviron file, as Rstudio server does not export OS wide environment variables)